# Two different click and two actions jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
//some action
}
//another action on same link when scrolled down.
$('.fixed .menu').click(function() {
//some action
}
```

is it possible On same page when i click .menu, some action has to happen, once i scroll and click same link adding .fixed then some other action has to happen?

Comment: The easiest way would be to keep one click event on .menu but inside the function test if it has the class .fixed to create a different workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check if it has the fixed class

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('fixed')){
     // fixed class code
   } else {
     // other code
   }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie for quick response. below code dosent working for me:
$('.menu').click(function() {
 if($(this).hasClass('fixed')){
  $('.business-menu').slideDown(300);
  $('.business-nav').animate({
  height: 125
  }, 300);
} 
else {
$('.business-menu').slideDown(300);
 $('.business-nav').animate({
  height: 155
  }, 300);
 }    
});